# SharePoint Returning a 401.1 for a Specific User/Computer

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

We have a SharePoint Services 3.0 site set up supporting about 300 users right now. This report is isolated and has never been duplicated. We have one AD user who cannot log into the SharePoint site with his account from his machine and is subsequently returned a 401.1 error.

If any other user tries to log on with their account from his machine, it works okay. If he moves to another machine and logs on, it works okay. The only solution to this point has been to install FireFox on the machine. When he authenticates with FF, everything is okay. 

**Remedies tried so far:**
Cleared cookies/cache
Turned off/on Integrated Windows Authentication in IE
Downgraded IE 8 to IE 6
Removed site from Intranet Sites zone
Renamed the machine
Disjoined/Rejoined Domain

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the system logs as well as the sharepoint logs.  It is very hard to determine the true cause without this information.

Comment: Both the system logs (on the users PC) and the SharePoint logs are empty. In fact I think it's strange that SharePoint doesn't show the failed authentication in the log.

Comment: Occam's Razor my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks similar to this [one](http://weblogs.asp.net/felipeferreira/archive/2008/03/11/fixing-sharepoint-401-1-http-errors.aspx).

Since it works with FF but not with IE, it is definitely a problem related to an authentication mechanism used by IE but not by FF, such as Windows Integration. If the procedure described in the link above does not solve the problem, I suggest you have a look into IE's configuration.